# How to use UPDATE and JOIN in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update

I have a table "A" with two columns - Name and Description. table "B" has Functional name and OPEX_Mapping. The common field between Table A and B is "Description" and "Functional Name".

Am looking to update Table "A" to have a column "OPEX_Mapping" coming from table B.But am getting an error as "Cannot update ... field not updatable"

**MS ACCESS SQL CODE:**

```
UPDATE A LEFT JOIN B ON A.DESCRIPTION = B.[Function Name] SET A.OPEX_Mapping = [B].[OPEX_Mapping];
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You may need a primary key on `B([Function Name])` so MS Access knows this is 1-1.

Comment: It is possible that an `INNER JOIN` is needed in an`UPDATE` query like this rather than a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Please show us Table Design of `B` with cursor on `OPEX_Mapping` for details so we can see data types, formatting, any validation rules, etc.